# Implement Interface through class member

Tags: c#, .net-6.0

Is it possible in C# to implement an Interface through a class member without explicitly returning the members implementation?
I want something like this

```
interface IAttachement
{
    byte[] Data { get; }
    string Name { get; }
    long Size { get; }
}

class Attachement : IAttachement
{
    public byte[] Data { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public long Size { get; set; }
}

class Request : IAttachement
{
    public Attachement Attachement { get; set; } : IAttachement
}
```

Instead of

```
class Request : IAttachement
{
    public Attachement Attachement { get; set; }
    public byte[] Data => Attachement.Data;
    public string Name => Attachement.Name;
    public long Size => Attachement.Size;
}
```

Comment: Haha, this is basically what [`by`](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/delegation.html) does in Kotlin. Unfortunately, I don't think C# has a similar feature. :(

Comment: That's awesome, now I at least know that it's called Delegation Pattern and that my idea was not that far off!

Comment: I am not sure about your use case, but why not add an additional interface IHasAttachment and add the Attachment there (Request inherits IHasAttachment)? I think that this is called composition .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, this isn't a feature that C# offers.

You can delegate interface implementation to a field/property/member, but you have to do it explicitly, as in your example.

If you would like this feature adding to the language, you can raise an issue [here](https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang).

Comment: That's sad. Thanks for the link, I'll check this out when I got some time!

Comment: The request has been submitted multiple times already: https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/13952

Comment: @Ksdmg - Useful context, although it's worth noting there's nothing wrong with submitting it again, it's not unheard of for features to be rejected but then added later

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to implement an interface through a class member without explicitly returning the member's implementation. In order for a class to implement an interface, it must provide an implementation for all members of the interface, either explicitly or implicitly. In your example the `Request` class needs to provide an implementation for the `Data`, `Name`, and `Size` properties of the `IAttachment` interface, either by implementing them directly or by delegating to the `Attachement` member.